# Oracle SQL - Query to select string between curly Brackets

Tags: sql, oracle, regexp-substr

I'm looking for an query to select string between curly Brackets , I can utilize in Oracle SQL or PL/SQL.

Here is an example TABLE1 to work with:

| ID | LIST |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | `Depto:={x1,x2} Code:={house}` |
| 2 | `Depto:={y1,x1} Code:={house,garden}` |
| 3 | `Depto:={x1,x2} Code:={house} Depto:={x3,x4}` |
| 4 | `Code:={house,garden} Depto:={y1,x1}` |

Result expected:

| ID | LIST | DEPTO | CODE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | `Depto:={x1,x2} Code:={house}` | `x1:x2` | `house` |
| 2 | `Depto:={y1,x1} Code:={house,garden}` | `y1:x1` | `house:garden` |
| 3 | `Depto:={x1,x2} Code:={house} Depto:={x3,x4}` | `x1:x2:x3:x4` | `house` |
| 4 | `Code:={house,garden} Depto:={y1,x1}` | `y1:x1` | `house:garden` |

I tried this query:

```
SELECT id, list, regexp_substr(list, '\Depto:={([^}]+)\}', 1,1,NULL,1) AS Depto, regexp_substr(list, '\Code:={([^}]+)\}', 1,1,NULL,1) AS Code FROM table1
```

but with this query I extrated only the first string.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You could use recursive subquery factoring (or a hierarchical query) to extract all of the depto/code elements from each list:

```
with rcte (id, list, lvl, depto, code) as (
  select id, list,
    1,
    regexp_substr(list, 'Depto:={(.*?)}', 1, 1, null, 1),
    regexp_substr(list, 'Code:={(.*?)}', 1, 1, null, 1)
  from table1
  union all
  select id, list,
    lvl + 1,
    regexp_substr(list, 'Depto:={(.*?)}', 1, lvl + 1, null, 1),
    regexp_substr(list, 'Code:={(.*?)}', 1, lvl + 1, null, 1)
  from rcte
  where regexp_substr(list, 'Depto:={(.*?)}', 1, lvl + 1, null, 1) is not null
  or regexp_substr(list, 'Code:={(.*?)}', 1, lvl + 1, null, 1) is not null
)
select * from rcte
```

| ID | LIST | LVL | DEPTO | CODE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Depto:={x1,x2} Code:={house} | 1 | x1,x2 | house |
| 2 | Depto:={y1,x1} Code:={house,garden} | 1 | y1,x1 | house,garden |
| 3 | Depto:={x1,x2} Code:={house} Depto:={x3,x4} | 1 | x1,x2 | house |
| 4 | Code:={house,garden} Depto:={y1,x1} | 1 | y1,x1 | house,garden |
| 3 | Depto:={x1,x2} Code:={house} Depto:={x3,x4} | 2 | x3,x4 | *null* |

and then use `listagg` to aggregate them together:

```
with rcte (id, list, lvl, depto, code) as (
  select id, list,
    1,
    regexp_substr(list, 'Depto:={(.*?)}', 1, 1, null, 1),
    regexp_substr(list, 'Code:={(.*?)}', 1, 1, null, 1)
  from table1
  union all
  select id, list,
    lvl + 1,
    regexp_substr(list, 'Depto:={(.*?)}', 1, lvl + 1, null, 1),
    regexp_substr(list, 'Code:={(.*?)}', 1, lvl + 1, null, 1)
  from rcte
  where regexp_substr(list, 'Depto:={(.*?)}', 1, lvl + 1, null, 1) is not null
  or regexp_substr(list, 'Code:={(.*?)}', 1, lvl + 1, null, 1) is not null
)
select id, list,
  listagg(depto, ',') within group (order by lvl) as depto,
  listagg(code, ',') within group (order by lvl) as code
from rcte
group by id, list
```

| ID | LIST | DEPTO | CODE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Depto:={x1,x2} Code:={house} | x1,x2 | house |
| 2 | Depto:={y1,x1} Code:={house,garden} | y1,x1 | house,garden |
| 3 | Depto:={x1,x2} Code:={house} Depto:={x3,x4} | x1,x2,x3,x4 | house |
| 4 | Code:={house,garden} Depto:={y1,x1} | y1,x1 | house,garden |

If you want colons instead of commas then you can just `replace` those, either before or after aggregating.

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=d16f103c8c3d0a40a5c32a956c0bbb04) including a version replacing commas with colons.

Answer (score 1):

You probably would need to escape the metacharacters in your regex.  Consider this version:

```sql
SELECT id, list,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(list, 'Depto:=\{(.*?)\}', 1, 1, NULL, 1) AS Depto,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(list, 'Code:=\{(.*?)\}', 1, 1, NULL, 1) AS Code
FROM table1
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo

Comment: Yes it worked, I just would like to know if is possible to merge the string, if you give a look in my example ID=3 the "Depto" are twice in the same string, the output should be x1,x2,x3,x4

Comment: I don't know of any way to do a regex find all from Oracle, sans resorting to something like a proc or formal script.  I didn't see that you have multiple matches within each string.

Answer (score 1):

The structure of input data looks quite simple, so you may also try to convert it to JSON and parse that JSON. It will not require recursion to split parts into different items.

> ```
> with table1(id, list) as (
>   select rownum, column_value
>   from table(sys.odcivarchar2list(
>     'Depto:={x1,x2} Code:={house}'
>     , 'Depto:={y1,x1} Code:={house,garden}'
>     , 'Depto:={x1,x2} Code:={house} Depto:={x3,x4}'
>     , 'Code:={house,garden} Depto:={y1,x1}'
>   ))
> )
> , a as (
>   select
>     id
>     , list
>     /*Replace each pair <Code>:=<Value> to JSON-like structure*/
>     , '['
>       || regexp_replace(list || ' ', '(\w+):=\{([^}]+)\} ', '{"\1":"\2"},')
>       || ']' as res
>   from table1
> )
> select
>   a.id
>   , translate(
>       replace(json_query(res, '$[*].."Depto"' with array wrapper), ',', ':')
>       , ' "[]'
>       , ' '
>   ) as depto
>   , trim(both '"' from json_query(res, '$[*].."Code"')) as code
> from a
> ```

> | ID | DEPTO | CODE |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | x1:x2 | house |
> | 2 | y1:x1 | house,garden |
> | 3 | x1:x2:x3:x4 | house |
> | 4 | y1:x1 | house,garden |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=d2613a4b19dee32acbe058450626ffaa)*